# Get browser proxy IP and port using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, proxy, http-proxy

Is there any way, using pure JavaScript (no APIs, externals), to detect the IP address and port number of the proxy being used by the browser?

I don't need to know the IP address that the proxy is hiding, just the proxy IP.

Answer (score -1):

### **[ipinfo.io](http://ipinfo.io)**

**Try it:** https://ipinfo.io/json

```
$.getJSON('https://ipinfo.io/json', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "ip": "39.63.18.86",
  "city": "Gujranwala",
  "region": "Punjab",
  "country": "PK",
  "loc": "32.1617,74.1883",
  "postal": "38850",
  "org": "AS45595 Pakistan Telecom Company Limited"
}
```

**Limitations:**

- 1,000 requests per day

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841164/2817985)

Comment: No APIs or externals